# How to customize the format for a field that is a duration?

Tags: jspresso

In my model.groovy, i have an entity with a lot of fields that are of type duration.

For a particular field, I would be able to customize the format for either enter or display the data.
Example :  instead of entering "90 minutes" that is the default format, I would be able to enter 1h30.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as of Jspresso 4.3, this is not possible. Feel free to open a RFE on [GitHub](https://github.com/jspresso/jspresso-ce/issues) for it.